# What process states contribute to the load average of a server?

Tags: linux, unix, process, operating-system, signals

It was an interview question which I attend with phone screening.

I gave the answer as :
`Running State (R)`, `interruptible State (S)` and the `IO wait`.

But I think I may understand the question wrongly or something could be missing in my answer I just feel that.

So I checked over the internet find some silly scattered information. Still I'm not sure what's the answer is.

What do you think about the answer of this question ?

Comment: This is highly implementation dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way of calculating load average, it depends on the OS. Here's [Linux's load calculator](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/proc.c?v=3.14#L90):

```
long calc_load_fold_active(struct rq *this_rq)
{
    long nr_active, delta = 0;

    nr_active = this_rq->nr_running;
    nr_active += (long) this_rq->nr_uninterruptible;

    if (nr_active != this_rq->calc_load_active) {
        delta = nr_active - this_rq->calc_load_active;
        this_rq->calc_load_active = nr_active;
    }

    return delta;
}
```

The processes Linux counts as active for the purpose of load averages are Running (R) and Uininterruptible (D).

Interruptible Sleep (S) is not counted, and neither is Defunct (Z) or Stopped (T).

Comment: woow, it just nailed it! I think I learned an habit now, if something you cannot find digging the source code! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Nice, but explaining this in text would be very helpful for non-programmers.